# Terraform for processes

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

Can Terraform be used in processes?
Or is it used strictly for independent versioning of components?
I know dependencies (between components) can be set, but it's not enough.

Let me give an example, say I need to update certain resources, but in a particular sequence.

- Stop a VM, backup a db, upgrade a db, start VM
- Reroute a Pub/Sub flow to a new BigQuery table,
  alter the old BigQuery table,
  reroute the Pub/Sub flow back to the original table,
  copy the data from the new table to the old one,
  drop the old table
- etc

Think of something like liquibase, but for devops.

I found something vaguely [similar](https://terraformarchitect.com/quick-recipes-terraform/custom-script-from-within-a-terraform-module/), but it feels way too hacky.
Far too much can go wrong.

Comment: Terraform is not designed to accomplish those features. Yes, you can hack something together but don't. Use the Google Cloud CLI `gcloud` or better, write software to perform tasks.

Comment: @JohnHanley 
My plan was to write something on my own. I was just hoping I did not have to. That there is some framework for this well known problem.
On the topic of `gcloud` and similar CLI: be aware that not all options are exposed in it. Not even in `beta` nor `alpha` variants. Libs have better coverage, yet not 100% in GCP.
Only the REST api seems to have a 100% coverage.

Answer (score 1):

Today's Terraform is not designed to handle the orchestration of a specific sequence of changes like that on its own.

You can potentially use Terraform as *part* of a solution to achieve something like this. To do so, you would need to write a Terraform configuration that uses input variables to represent all of the different intermediate steps in the process, in each case describing how the system ought to be defined (the "desired state") at that step.

You would then write a script outside of Terraform which includes a mixture of Terraform-driven changes and other imperative actions. Taking your second PubSub case as an example, the sequence in your external script might be:

1. Run `terraform apply` with some input variables that cause it to declare a new BigQuery table alongside the old one, and route the PubSub events to the new table.

   Terraform will propose to create the new table and change the pubsub rule to refer to it.
2. Run `terraform apply` with the input variables changed so that the desired state of the old BigQuery table is different.

   Terraform will propose to update the old BigQuery table to match the new desired state.
3. Use an external tool to replicate the data from one table to the other.

   This step is not one for Terraform, because it doesn't involve a change to "desired state" of the infrastructure, but rather a change to the system's real data.
4. Run `terraform apply` with the input variables changed so that the old table is no longer declared at all.

   Terraform will propose to destroy the old table.

The Terraform steps in the list above seem to suggest the need for at least two input variables in the configuration:

- `bigquery_tables`: A map of objects describing the BigQuery tables that should exist. The unique keys of this map will differentiate the tables.
- `active_bigquery_table`: A string specifying the key from the map of BigQuery tables that the PubSub rule should route to.

The steps above would then be translated to Terraform changes like this:

1. Add a new entry to the `bigquery_tables` map, while retaining the old one. Also change `active_bigquery_table` to refer to the new table.
2. Change the old entry from the `bigquery_tables` map, while leaving the new one unchanged.
3. (not a Terraform step)
4. Remove the old entry from the `bigquery_tables` map, while retaining the new one.

Although it is technically possible to use Terraform in this way, that doesn't mean that it's necessarily the most effective way to achieve this goal. It involves including some extra input variables in your Terraform configuration, and then orchestrating changes to those variables using an external script, which is an unusual way to use Terraform.

It's debatable whether using Terraform as I've described has enough benefits to justify that additional complexity vs. just implementing all of the steps directly as API changes driven by a script written specifically for this purpose.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was afraid of.
Tbh, doing a straight script sounds a lot better than involving Terraform.

Trraform has that ORM vibe unfortunately.
Some ORMs have features where one would write a query in some meta language, and the ORM will translate is somehow to vendor specific SQL queries.
Problem is that those queries are often well garbage.

I'm just surprised that there is no out-of-the-box solution to this problem.
Like I mentioned, in SQL world there are frameworks like Liquibase who deal with this problem quite nicely.

Comment: There might well be other tools available for this; I was only meaning to speak for Terraform in particular, which is not designed to solve the problem you described.